# How protect placemarks created in Google Earth?

Tags: google-earth

I've created placemarks in Google Earth but they are easily moved by accident by clicking somewhere near them. Is there a way to easily protect these from such accidental movement?

Comment: Which version of Google Earth are you seeing this in?  Google Earth on the web/browser (https://earth.google.com), or Google Earth Pro (the desktop application)?  I can't seem to reproduce the issue in either one... both seem to require a click to start editing a placemark, but if I'm missing something, please provide more details on how to reproduce.  I have seen a similar issue in Google My Maps.

Comment: Christiaan, Thanks very much for your response. I'm using earth.google.com. I created a project, and was using the measuring tool to map out a "census" route along a road network, and was measuring every 2 km straight-line distance from a starting point, and crteating a new placemark at each of those. Thus, as I measured, I had to keep moving the "scene" over the landscape, so I would click to grab the landscape and move it over, to extend my "measuring stick". sometimes in doing so, I would apparently click close enough to an existing placemark, to inadvertently move it to some random place.